# Any way to force stop eJabberd?

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm pretty new to eJabberd and Erlang. as I was developing a custom registration module for ejabberd, at some point I had to use the inets application, so I start it using `application:start(inets)` in `start` method. I also wanted to stop it in the stop method, but I made a small mistake and wrote `application:stop(inet)` instead of `application:stop(inets)`. apparently, it was no small mistake! now my ejabberd is apparently frozen somewhere while closing. `ejabberdctl status` returns

```
The node ejabberd@localhost is stopping with status: started
Failed RPC connection to the node ejabberd@localhost: {'EXIT',
                                                       {timeout,
                                                        {gen_server,call,
                                                         [application_controller,
                                                          which_applications]}}}
```

and `ejabberdctl start` returns

```
ERROR: The ejabberd node 'ejabberd@localhost' is already running.
```

but I cannot connect to the server using any xmpp messenger. is there any way I can somehow force it to close?

I'd appreciate any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally! after learning more about erlang nodes and ejabberd I found a bash script [here](https://gist.github.com/robertoaloi/8884096) 
that would allow you to kill any erlang node. After running `epmd -names` I made sure ejabberd was running on "ejabberd" node and not "ejabberd@localhost", All I had to do was to excute

```
./kill-erlang-node.sh ejabberd
```

I successfully managed to restart ejabberd using `ejabberdctl start`

oh! and apparently stoping inets was a crazy thing to do! don't do it! ever!!

Comment: Yes, if you stop inets, you lose ability to cluster (or to contact that node, with another local node).

Comment: @Mickaël hmm I see, yeah I thought other parts of ejabberd must be using it, but didn't know how, thanks for the insight :)